# Django-el-pagination not working, pagination not showing up

Tags: python, django

So I tried installing django-el-pagination, but apparently, it doesn't want to load on my web page. Every package is installed but it won't show. Here is what I did:

```js
def index(request):
    course_list = Course.objects.all()
    page = request.GET.get('page', 1)
    paginator = Paginator(course_list, 1)
    try:
        courses1 = paginator.page(page)
    except PageNotAnInteger:
        courses1 = paginator.page(1)
    except EmptyPage:
        courses1 = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
    context = {
        'courses1': courses1,
        'courses': Course.objects.all(),
        'faculties': Faculty.objects.all(),
        'departments': Department.objects.all(),
        'studies': StudyProgramme.objects.all(),
        'teachers': Teacher.objects.all()
    }
    return render(request, 'courses/index.html', context)
```

```html
 <div id="crs">
                        <h3>All courses</h3>
                        <ul>
                            {% paginate courses1 %}
                            {% for course in courses1 %}
                                <li><a href={{ course.slug }}>{{ course.name }}</a></li>
                            {% endfor %}
                            {% show_pages %}
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change {% paginate courses1 %} to {% paginate courses1 using course %}. or {{% paginate courses1 using "course" %}